# webpack generating chunks for nested link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am doing route-based code splitting using React.lazy. In some pages, there are link to other pages. In that case, Its creating chunk for that linked page also.

webpack

```
optimization: {
      runtimeChunk: 'single',
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          vendor: {
            test: new RegExp(
              /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            ),
            chunks: 'all',
            name: 'vendor',
            enforce: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
```

Routes.js

```
const Home = React.lazy(() => import('./Pages/Home' /* webpackChunkName: "home" */));
const Profile = React.lazy(() => import('./Pages/Profile' /* webpackChunkName: "profile" */))
const Settings = React.lazy(() => import('./Pages/Settings' /* webpackChunkName: "Settings" */))


const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/Profile"  component={Profile}/>
                <Route path="/Settings"  component={Settings}/>
            </Switch>
        </Suspense>
    )
}
```

Home

```
export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Home</p>
            <Link to="/profile">Go to Profile</Link>
            <Link to="/settings">Go to Settings</Link>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here I am getting below chunks -

```
app.[hash].js
runtime.[hash].js
vendor.[hash].js
Home.[hash].js
Profile.[hash].js
Home~Profile.[hash].js
Home~Setting.[hash].js
```

What is the reason of getting last two chunks?

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect content of this chunks by some webpack bundle analyzer too see whats inside. Most likely there is some vendor packages similar between two pages so from performance perspective it is better to put this packages in shared chunk instead of duplicating those packages in each  chunk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my question is why there are two extra chunks Home~Profile.[hash].js, Home~Setting.[hash].js? Though the content is same in Home~Profile.[hash].js and Profile[hash].js

Comment: Answering your question why: because of webpack chunks optimisation. Your Home Profile and Settings pages have some imports. Some of those imports are the same. In order to optimise chunks size webpack splits some imports from Home page and its code to Home.[hash].js chunk then imports which is used in Home and Profile pages goes to Home-Profile.[hash].js shared chunk. If there is no such optimisations clients hove to download those shared imports twice first when they visit Home page and second time when they visit Profile page.

Comment: With this optimisation clients download Home.[hash].js + Home-Profile.[hash].js chunks while visiting Home page and then visiting Profile only small Profile.[hash].js needed

Comment: Got your point. anyway Is there any disable it from webpack config?

Comment: The question is why you want to do that? You hate your users? just joking :) It should be a very specific reason to avoid this optimization. According to docs https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/ there is no such option. Possible you can use a new entry point for each page but this really depends on why you need this